# Trying to remember a sci-fi short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to remember this scifi short story I stumble on from time to time. The only thing I can recall is that the universe or solar system was ending, and some scientists went into a vault to gather a few seconds more of data before everything ended.

Comment: It was that one. Just couldn't remember any of the plot details.

Comment: I remember it specifically because their efforts are so charmingly English. The world's ending, but that's no reason not to carry on regardless.